# Batch file won't escape quotations

Tags: windows-10, batch, batch-file

Sorry if this seems kind of basic but I'm new to this. I thought I had this all worked out but when I moved it to the actual environment I need it to run in it stopped working.
Everything is working up until I try to split up `"%result%"` At that point I'm grabbing a line of text that looks like this

```
"Avanti B & C 3",9,2,18,1,11.625,"11 5/8",8.98438,"8 31/32",0.76563,"49/64",162,"Partition"...etc
```

I would like to retrieve Avanti B & C 3,162,Partition. As a test I tried this but I can't get it to return the first string.

```
set result="Avanti B & C 3",6,2,9,1,14.625,"14 5/8",82,"82",0.75,"3/4",72,"Unfinished Right End",2181,"3/4 2s Quartersawn Maple",0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,"Tall Cabinet W/ routed pe","","078b0072","1LE","Library 1044","",0,0,"*078b0072*","","Default","N:\CVLabels\078p0072.jpg"
for /f tokens^=1^ delims^=^" %%i in ("%result%") do set _jobname=%%i
echo %_jobname%
pause
```

*Edited to get to the point of what I need

Comment: Without knowing the content of your input files, nor the output or error messages you get, it's difficult/impossible to help.

Comment: @LotPings edited the post to simplify the question hopefully

Answer (score 1):

`tokens=1` is the default and doesn't need to be expressed.

When stripping the double quotes from a string containing poisenous characters like `<>|&` they need to be escaped before with a caret.

The problem is enclosing `%result%` in double qutes, this creates a pair of double quotes at the begin leaving the `&` unquoted and unescaped. When escaping remember that it get lost once exposed.

```
:: Q:\Test\2019\02\28\SU_1410257_2.cmd
@Echo off
set result="Avanti B & C 3",6,2,9,1,14.625,"14 5/8",82,"82",0.75,"3/4",72,"Unfinished Right End",2181,"3/4 2s Quartersawn Maple",0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,"Tall Cabinet W/ routed pe","","078b0072","1LE","Library 1044","",0,0,"*078b0072*","","Default","N:\CVLabels\078p0072.jpg"
for /f delims^=^" %%i in ("%result:&=^&%") do set "_jobname=%%i"
echo %_jobname:&=^&%
pause
```

Sample output:

```
> Q:\Test\2019\02\28\SU_1410257_2.cmd
Avanti B & C 3
Drücken Sie eine beliebige Taste . . .
```

**EDIT variant as requested per comment:**

```
:: Q:\Test\2019\02\28\SU_1410257_3.cmd
@Echo off
set result="Avanti B & C 3",6,2,9,1,14.625,"14 5/8",82,"82",0.75,"3/4",72,"Unfinished Right End",2181,"3/4 2s Quartersawn Maple",0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,"Tall Cabinet W/ routed pe","","078b0072","1LE","Library 1044","",0,0,"*078b0072*","","Default","N:\CVLabels\078p0072.jpg"
for /f "tokens=1,8,9delims=," %%A in ("%result:&=^&%") do (
  set "_jobname=%%~A"
  set "token8=%%B"
  Set "token9=%%C"
)
echo _jobname=%_jobname:&=^&%
echo token8=%token8%
echo token9=%token9%
pause
```

Sample output:

```
> Q:\Test\2019\02\28\SU_1410257_2.cmd
_jobname=Avanti B & C 3
token8=82
token9="82"
```

Comment: This is working for getting that first string, thank you. How would I get multiple strings ie 1,8,9

Comment: Provided the strings in double quotes do not contain commas change the delims to a comma and begin with the for var `%%A` or `%%a` (they are distinct). See changed answer.

Comment: Now that I've really comprehended what you are saying I understand why it worked before. Our job titles usually never have ampersands in them and I can make sure that never happens again.